# Is there any difference between Task.Factory.StartNew<T> & Task<T>.Factory.StartNew?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, task

From my understanding, they are the same but I'm curious to know if one has any advantage over the other. If not, why the team bothered to declare two versions of the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the MSDN documentation for both the functions:

For `TaskFactory.StartNew<TResult>`: Calling StartNew is functionally equivalent to creating a `Task<TResult>` using one of its constructors...

For `TaskFactory<TResult>.StartNew`: Calling StartNew is functionally equivalent to creating a task by using one of the `Task<TResult>` constructors...

There is in fact a slight difference from the functional point of view:

The first time you use a `Task<T>` class, the static constructor creates a new `TaskFactory<T>` object and stores it. This is in fact a small object, but takes memory that will be held until the end of AppDomain's lifetime but `Task`'s static constructor just creates a single `TaskFactory` object.

So if you will be using a lot of types to create tasks for, use `Task.Factory.StartNew<T>` because you won't make the runtime create all that `TaskFactory<T>` objects. 
If for just one or two types, assign `Task<T>.Factory` to a variable and use it for a simpler code.

UPDATE: As  @Kirill Shlenskiy mentioned in the comments, I made a mistake. So there is REALLY no difference between these two.

Comment: I would like to examine your second point re `TaskFactory<T>` allocation. `Task.Factory.StartNew<T>` returns a `Task<T>`, therefore the type initialiser for `Task<T>` has to run and allocate `Task<T>.Factory` (or more specifically the `s_factory` static readonly field backing it) behind the covers, regardless of which method you use.

Comment: Thanks Kirill. I made a mistake.